# Django Error: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-views

i am getting this error. i am trying to loop through posts to display the posts that are part of the collection. What should i change this to?

relevant info:

models.py

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='collection_posts', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def collection_detail_view(request, pk):
    collection = Collection.objects.get(id=pk)
    posts = Collection.posts.all() #this is the error

    context = {
        'collection': collection,
        'posts': posts  
    }

    return render(request, 'collection_detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are calling `all()` directly to the `posts` field of the model. Not to the posts of the `collection` object. Basically you're calling your class instead of your instance.

Do the following instead:

```py
posts = collection.posts.all() #note the lower case
```